# Google Apss Script for E-mail remainders for every 20 days from start days till end date

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm new to coding and i have to write an apps script code to get an email remainder for every 20 days interval from start date till the end date.

```
 function emailAlert() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  lastCol = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange( 2, 1, lastRow-1, lastCol);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var date = new Date(row[3]); // make the sheet value a date object
    //Logger.log('original value = '+date);
    //Logger.log('method 1 : '+new Date(date.getTime()+5*3600000*24));
    //var myVar=100;
    //for (var j=20; j<myVar.length; j+=20){
    twentyDaysFromStartDate = new Date(date.setDate(date.getDate() + j ));
    var formattedtwentyDaysFromStartDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(twentyDaysFromStartDate), "ET", "dd/MM/yyyy");
    //}
     Logger.log ('Twenty Days From StartDate : ' +formattedtwentyDaysFromStartDate);
    var expireDateFormat = Utilities.formatDate(
      new Date(row[4]),
      'ET',
      'dd/MM/yyy'
    );
    Logger.log ('Expired Date : '+expireDateFormat);
    var subject = '';
    var message =
      ' Controllare documenti Progetto Formativo ' +
      '\n' +
      ' CODICE FISCALE: ' +
      row[0] +
      '\n' +
      ' NOME: ' +
      row[1] +
      '\n' +
      ' COGNOME: ' +
      row[2] +
      '\n' +
      ' DATA INIZIO: ' +
      date +
      '\n' +
      ' DATA FINE: ' +
      expireDateFormat;

      var today = Utilities.formatDate(
      new Date(),
     'ET',
     'dd/MM/yyyy',
      );
      Logger.log('Today Date :' + today);

      if(formattedtwentyDaysFromStartDate <= expireDateFormat) //CHECKS EXPIRE DATE, IS LESS THAN TWENTY DAYS FROM START DATE
      {
        
      if(formattedtwentyDaysFromStartDate === today)
        {
          var subject =
          'Progetto formativo' +
          row[0] +
          ' - ' +
          expireDateFormat;
          MailApp.sendEmail('email@gmail.com', subject, message);
          
        }
     }
  }
}
```

This code works fine for sending mail remainder 20th day from the start day (for every 20th day), but if i want another remainder on 40th day this code is not working, i tried for loop but i get result as undefined. can anyone help me.
thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Email Remainder for every 20 days after the start date till the End date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69344523/email-remainder-for-every-20-days-after-the-start-date-till-the-end-date)

Comment: thanks for the link, but that is not what im looking for. I want a loop that sends email remainder every 20 days interval.

Comment: Use the code shown in the [duplicate thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69344523/email-remainder-for-every-20-days-after-the-start-date-till-the-end-date) in a loop, feeding it different start and end dates each time.

Comment: sorry to bother but i dont understand what that code does to send mail remainder in every 20 days interval?

Comment: Run your email sending function once a day using a time-driven trigger. In that function, use the code in the duplicate thread to check whether the dates in a particular row should result in an email to get sent.

Comment: Some of the best resources for learning Google Apps Script are listed at [Apps Script at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info).