# How to construct time based if statements in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am attempting to construct some simple logic for events happening in my spreadsheet before a certain time (2pm) each day. I want the function to tell me if the date entered represented in this case by the variable "tradeTime" is before or after 2pm CT. No matter what sample data I have provided the if statement always returns "Trade time is not less than 2pm"
[image]

Comment: I think that `Utilities.formatDate()` returns the string value. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String)) In your script, 2 string values are compared. I thought that this was the reason for your issue. So, in order to compare the time, I thought that this thread might be useful. https://stackoverflow.com/q/19004950 If this was not useful, I apologize. If this was useful, I would like to flag your question as the duplicated question for it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69347105/7215091

Comment: Add  code and logs as text not as image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently comparing strings to each other which is not what you really want to do. Time or Date is easily converted to a numbers using the `valueOf()` function on a `Date` Object, see references for more information.

Therefore I propose the following:

```
function isEventBeforeDeadline(){
  const eventTime = new Date(2021,2,2,14).valueOf() 
  const deadline  = new Date(2021,2,2,14).valueOf()

  if( eventTime > deadline ) console.log("Too late")
  if( eventTime < deadline ) console.log("Made it")
  if( eventTime == deadline ) console.log("Perfect")
}
```

Please also see comments on your post.

- Be more specific with where these dates are coming from, e.g. from a Sheet, API, or elsewhere. We assume you will not enter dates manually everyday.
- Do not post images of code, post code of code. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) > Syntax Highlighting for Code
- You are likely to need to build a Trigger which runs automatically. Then the code needs to be modified check for todays date, I assume. [Here are the docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually) for that.

### Reference

[- Date Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date)

[- Date.valueOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/valueOf)